# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>...</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prods/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Comment: A NoSuchMethodError is most likely due a version conflict of the involved libraries. The library which calls org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create is therefore not compatible with the used glassfish version.

Comment: I used some similar xml files with here https://afsinka.wordpress.com/2015/12/27/restful-web-service-example-with-jersey-2-and-tomcat-8/

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks. I am new to Jersey and tomcat. Can I ask what is the relationship between `org.glassfish.jersey.containers` and `tomcat`? why we need `org.glassfish.jersey.containers` when I run `mvn clean package` and deploy `war` to the `webapps` fold of tomcat?

Comment: Is there `<artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>` in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 4):

you need to `hk2-api` dependency into your `pom.xml` you can find it below:
and delete the `.m2` directory clean and rebuild project and update project and run it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b42</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue I've faced recently and tried to check all jar's dependencies :) However, there is an easy solution for maven projects. Maybe it solves your issue.
Add this maven plugin;

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
<configuration>
    <rules>
        <dependencyConvergence />
    </rules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run this;

mvn enforcer:enforce