# REST WS fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy error

Tags: rest, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am facing an issue while creating on a simple REST WS and deploying it on tomcat server. I have created a simple rest WS using jersey archetype as:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
            -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
            -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example \
            -DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

and the pom.xml looks like:

```
<build>
    <finalName>simple-service-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

So with this pom.xml and a simple REST service that sends hello world, I am able to build the project and get the war file.

So now when I deploy the war file and try to access the web service, it gives me an error as:

```
Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy
org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:114)
org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:86)
org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:79)
org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:97)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
```

I tried the solution that is being suggested earlier in stackoverflow for the issue above, and that is to use HK2 version 2.4.* or above, and when I do that and create the war file and deploy it, accessing the WS gives a different error and that is:

```
Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98)
java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
```

Would be grateful if someone can please provide some light into this issue. I am using JDK1.8 to compile my project, and deploying it on tomcat 9.0.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of all the `<version>`s for all your Jersey deps. That's what [BOM](https://hackernoon.com/maven-bill-of-materials-dependency-b6eb88f5c188)s are for... so you don't use incompatible versions like you are doing.

Comment: Hi Paul, If I comment out the versions of all the dependencies, it errs out while building with the error message:

[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar is missing. @ line 74, column 21
 @ 
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
  
  The project com.example.webapp:simple-service-webapp:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Learning\REST\JerseyTutorial\simple-service-webapp\pom.xml) has 1 error
    'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar is missing. @ line 74, column 21

Comment: I have commented out all the dependent version, leaving aside the version for <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>. That made it work fine. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this using Jersey 2.33 and Tomcat 9

I found this answer fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45687558/7105142

It looks like you are missing `hk2-api` from your pom